# Parameterizing/Sanitizing PreparedStatements that contain math functions and other columns

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have the PreparedStatement:

```
PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM test_table WHERE money > ABS(money2+?)");
ps.setInt(1,20);
```

"money" is a column that stores integers, and money2 is also a column that stores integers.

I am wondering how I would be able to parameterize the function "ABS" and the column "money2" as I did with the "ps.setInt(1,20)" for the number in the data. I wish to do this so that these queries aren't susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

Thanks

Comment: For function calls and stored procedures, use `CallableStatement` not `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: @Satya I see how a `CallableStatement` would work for functions, but I can't find anything on how you would use it for a query such as `UPDATE table_name  SET column_name = column2_name+1`. Is there anywhere that I can learn about this more? Everything I find seems to display that `CallableStatement`s are solely for functions. Thank you

Comment: @Satya You use a callable statement to call stored procedures (or in some database stored 'functions'). If you have a normal DML query that contains a function, then it is still normal DML and should be called using a prepared statement.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, So you are telling that its possible to call functions with sql using prepared statement, right. ok ill try this.

Comment: @Satya Depends on what you mean with functions. What some database call functions, are actually stored procedures, and in that case, you can call them with a callable statement. But if it is a 'normal' scalar function used in a query, then they are usually not callable, and can only be used in queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering how I would be able to parameterize the function "ABS" and the column "money2" as I did with the "ps.setInt(1,20)" for the number in the data.

You can't. Query parameters can only represent *values* in an SQL query. They cannot be used to insert table or column names, built-in functions, or SQL keywords.

So this is valid ...

```java
ps = conn.prepareStatement ("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE FirstName=?");
ps.setString(1, "Gord");
```

... but these are not:

```java
ps = conn.prepareStatement ("SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE ?='Gord'");
ps.setString(1, "FirstName");

ps = conn.prepareStatement ("SELECT * FROM ? WHERE FirstName='Gord'");
ps.setString(1, "tbl");

ps = conn.prepareStatement ("? * FROM tbl WHERE FirstName='Gord'");
ps.setString(1, "SELECT");
```

Comment: Ok, so since built-in functions and other columns are not values, using them in a PreparedStatement as part of the query will _not_ make them vulnerable for a SQL Injection, correct?

Comment: Correct. If they are part of the static query text then they are not vulnerable to SQL injection because they are never replaced by anything else.

Comment: Great, just the answer I was looking for! Thank you